# Web scraping with Scrapy and Python from one script and a javascript website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I'm trying to web scrape (with Scrapy) this website https://www.vaniercollege.qc.ca/sports-recreation/weekly-schedule/ from this script below

**script.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from threading import Thread


class CourtSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'full_page'
    allowed_domains = ['vaniercollege.qc.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://www.vaniercollege.qc.ca/sports-recreation/weekly-schedule/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract the entire HTML of the page
        page_html = response.text

        # You can either process the HTML right here, or yield it to be processed later
        yield {'html': page_html}

        # Optionally, save the HTML to a file
        with open('page_content.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(page_html)

# def run_spider_in_thread():
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})
process.crawl(CourtSpider)
process.start()  # Blocks until crawling is finished
```

When I get this data from this script, I have this object

```
<html>
    <title>You are being redirected...</title>
    <noscript>Javascript is required. Please enable javascript before you are allowed to see this page.</noscript>
    <script>
        var s = {}, u, c, U, r, i, l = 0, a, e = eval, w = String.fromCharCode, sucuri_cloudproxy_js = '',
        S = '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';
        L = S.length;
        U = 0;
        r = '';
        var A = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
        for (
```

I was trying to fetch the content but it always give me this page, how to enable javascript with scrapy and with only one script file?

Thanks

Comment: I think that [requests-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) supports scraping javascript pages, but if that doesn't work, you could always use [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro). `Playwright` would allow you to use codegen, and you could find the right way to scrape your page using the code generator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the website requires JavaScript to render its content, Scrapy alone won't be sufficient to scrape it. To handle websites that rely heavily on JavaScript, you'll need to use a headless browser like Selenium or Splash.

For this to work, you'll need to install chromedriver on your machine and selenium with pip.

Some example code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Set up Chrome WebDriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode (without GUI)
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')  # Avoid /dev/shm usage error
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")   
# Instantiate Chrome WebDriver
service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

# Load the webpage
url = 'https://www.vaniercollege.qc.ca/sports-recreation/weekly-schedule/'
driver.get(url)

# Set wait period for JavaScript to render the page
import time
time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the sleep time according to the page loading time

# Extract the page content
page_content = driver.page_source

# Save the HTML content to a file
with open('page_content.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(page_content)

# Quit the browser
driver.quit()
```

You can adjust the sleep time according to the page loading time to ensure that the page is fully loaded before extracting the content.

Answer (score 0):

In Scrapy, when extracting data from the response object, you typically use the `get()` or `getall()` methods on selectors to extract specific data and avoid including HTML elements.
Try this kind of code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class CourtSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'full_page'
    allowed_domains = ['vaniercollege.qc.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://www.vaniercollege.qc.ca/sports-recreation/weekly-schedule/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract specific data from the page using Scrapy selectors
        schedule_items = response.css('.schedule-item')

        for item in schedule_items:
            time = item.css('.time::text').get()
            activity = item.css('.activity::text').get()
            location = item.css('.location::text').get()

            yield {
                'time': time.strip() if time else None,
                'activity': activity.strip() if activity else None,
                'location': location.strip() if location else None
            }

# Run the spider
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS": {
        "items.json": {"format": "json"},
    },
})
process.crawl(CourtSpider)
process.start()  # Blocks until crawling is finished
```